# Hibernate ORM, how do I fetch inner join result set

Tags: hibernate

I am facing a little problem that I want to join two tables, and I want to retrieve the data through Hibernate ORM.

I have two tables. TableA has id column with PK constraint.
And the other one, TalbeB has id column(PK) and FK column referrencing TableA.

```
SELECT
    A.COL1,
    B.COL1,
    B.COL2
FROM
    TABLEA A 
    JOIN TABLEB ON A.COL1 = B.COL2
```

With above one single query, I want to retrieve data.
But I don't know what to do.

The below contents are what I have done, but it does not work yet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

and STS gives me an error:

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: could not resolve property: deptno of: com.winsplay.hibernate.bean.Emp [from com.winsplay.hibernate.bean.Emp emp join fetch Dept dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno]

It seems like emp bean doesn't have deptno property, so it raises an error.
But I want deptno(department code) to be located in Dept object, and I want Emp depends on Dept object.

Long story short,
I want to retrieve data from inner join query, using hibernate orm HQL.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots!

Comment: Remove that `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: Also, you don't (have to) specify joins on columns in JPQL ("on" clause). In your example, `SELECT e FROM Emp e` would be sufficient to access `e.getEName()` and `e.getDept().getDName()` on the result.

Comment: If you really wanted to retrieve employees and departments 'side-by-side' you'd have to select them as such: `SELECT e, d FROM Emp e JOIN e.dept d`.

Comment: I removed @JoinColumn in Emp class, and the string of createQuery is      "from Emp emp join fetch Dept dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno" but emp has no deptno column, instead, it has Dept object reference.